# laravel 5.2 how can i create simple search in my application

Tags: php, package, laravel-5

I want to add search in my website like the search of browser But my search will search in all my application and redirect to the page word in it.I read simple about elastic and algolia But I want simple search or package to use.

I did this form

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
                        <form method="GET"  action="{{url('search')}}" class="searchform">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search" style="float: left;"/>
                            <button type="submit"  ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

And don't know how to begin.I want algorithm,package or any guidance to start.
please any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this
http://fullstackstanley.com/read/simple-search-with-laravel-and-elasticsearch

**Setting up Elasticquent**

```
<?php
use Elasticquent\ElasticquentTrait;

class Post extends \Eloquent {
  use ElasticquentTrait;

  public $fillable = ['title', 'content', 'tags'];

  protected $mappingProperties = array(
    'title' => [
      'type' => 'string',
      "analyzer" => "standard",
    ],
    'content' => [
      'type' => 'string',
      "analyzer" => "standard",
    ],
    'tags' => [
      'type' => 'string',
      "analyzer" => "stop",
      "stopwords" => [","]
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: In your opinion Elastic search is the best for simple search?

Comment: @Sachin I got the idea but the link you provided is dead